# Python basic on classes

Tags: python, class

I have defined a class to process a file but get the following error when I try to instantiate the class and pass the filename.
Let me know what would be the problem?

```
>>> class fileprocess:
...    def pread(self,filename):
...        print filename
...        f = open(filename,'w')
...        print f
>>> x = fileprocess
>>> x.pread('c:/test.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: unbound method pread() must be called with
fileprocess instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x = fileprocess` does not mean `x` is an instance of `fileprocess`. It means `x` is now an alias for the `fileprocess` class.

You need to create an instance, using the `()`.

```
x = fileprocess()
x.pread('c:/test.txt')
```

In addition, based on your original code, you could use `x` to create class instances.

```
x = fileprocess
f = x() # creates a fileprocess
f.pread('c:/test.txt')
```

Answer (score 3):

`x = fileprocess` should be `x = fileprocess()`

Currently `x` is referring to the class itself, not an instance of the class.  So when you call `x.pread('c:/test.txt')` that's the same as calling `fileprocess.pread('c:/test.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

But why use write mode for read function? Maybe it's pwrite?